# Trying to move a file from Documents directory into /etc/bind Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to move/copy a file from the Documents directory into /etc/bind I tried:

```
sudo mv ~/Documents/Config_Files/db.example.lan /path/to/etc/bind/
```

I also tried:

```
sudo mv ~/Documents/Config_Files/db.example.lan /path/to/~//etc/bind/
```

But also got the error: "No such file or directory"

I am probably being dumb but I double checked spelling capitilisation and everything is correct but still won't come up as a directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't guide you much but, as you can see we use 'sudo mv' and this means we tell root to move it and you type '~' which means home directory...

So if you type:

```
sudo mv ~/Documents
```

this means

```
sudo mv /root/Documents
```

instead of

```
sudo mv /home/<xyz>/Documents
```

Try to give proper path and let me know if it works.!
example:

```
sudo mv /home/<username>/Documents/Config_Files/db.example.lan /etc/bind/
```

Comment: I used your suggestion but still got the same error but I tried to just remove "/path/to/" and have the destination just be "/etc/bind" and then it worked fine!
Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Cool I'll Edit the same then.

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are not related to stackoverflow! Thanks!